# Xamarin Forms - Changes to ObservableCollection are not updating the View

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ViewModel that, when a Command is executed, gets items from a service and adds those items to an ObservableCollection.
The ObservableCollection is bound to a ListView.

My problem is that adding items to the ObservableCollection is not automatically updating the View - the ListView stays empty.  If I call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemList))` then the ListView *is* updated - but shouldn't the ObservableCollection be taking care of raising this?

I am using the latest Xamarin.Forms (2.3.4.247).  This issue only affects Android - if I run on iOS it works correctly.

The ViewModel that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class ListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IService m_Service;

    public ListViewModel(IService service)
    {
        m_Service = service;
        ItemList = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        RefreshCommand = new Command(async () => await RefreshData());
    }

    public ICommand RefreshCommand {get;set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemList { get; private set; }

    private async Task RefreshData()
    {
        ItemList.Clear();
        var newItems = await m_Service.GetItems();

        if(newItems != null) {
            foreach(var n in newItems)
            {
                ItemList.Add(new ItemViewModel() { Title = n.Title });
            }               
    }
}
```

The Item ViewModel (that also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged)`:

```
public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string m_JobTitle;

    public ItemViewModel()
    {
    } 

    public string Title
    {
        get { return m_Title; }
        set
        {
            m_Title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
        }
    }        
}
```

The 'List' View:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:Test.Mobile.UI;assembly=Test.Mobile.UI"
         x:Class="Test.Mobile.UI.MyListView">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">      
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <ViewCell>
                      <ui:ItemView></ui:ItemView>
                  </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

The 'Item' View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:Test.Mobile.Models.Enums;assembly=Test.Mobile.Models"
         x:Class="Test.Mobile.UI.JobItemView">
    <ContentView.Content>
       <Label Text={Binding Title}/>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: What platform are you running on? Sometimes there are issues that require just setting ItemList = new ObservableCollection<Item>(newItems); in your RefreshData method

Comment: What package you use for ViewModelBase?MvvmLight?

Comment: I'm having the issue on Android.  I've just tested and iOS works correctly.  I've also tried ItemList = new ObservableCollection<Item>(newItems);, but the View still doesn't get updated unless I call OnPropertyChanged.  I wonder if it is just a weird Xamarin/Android issue?

Comment: You are trying to add objecs of type ItemViewModel to your ObservableCollection<Item> ItemList.  That isn't the error but I would like to know what you're trying to do.

ItemList.Add(new ItemViewModel()

Answer (score 1):

What version of Xamarin Forms are you using?

- Update your project to the latest version
- If you still having the issue, after adding the all elements try this:
  ItemList = new ObservableCollection(newItems);
- If that does not work, maybe could be an issue in your ViewModelBase.
  For Handle PropertyChanged I use this nice package 
  https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Comment: I'm on the latest version (2.3.4.247).  I don't think it is an issue with my ViewModelBase as all my other bound properties update correctly, and specifically raising the PropertyChanged event does update the View.  I think there is either some weird quirk or I am making a stupid mistake somewhere that I can't see..

Comment: @charlin I separated `ObservableCollection<Module> Modules` property on a _PageModel_ class. I initialize the _PageModel_  as _Model_ on the _ViewModel_ class that inherits _ViewModelBase_ (Prism). _Module_ has a property `isLocked`. If I update `Model.Modules[0].isLocked = true` the view is not updated.  Even if I call `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Model.Modules))`, still the view is not updated. But if I move the `ObservableCollection<Module> Modules` from _PageModel_ to the _ViewModel_ and call `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Modules))`, it updates the view. What was I doing wrong?